# Highlight asterisk in lstlisting

Tags: listings, highlighting

I would like to emphasise the asterisk used in `\begin{equation*}` in `lstlisting`. I have tried using `emph`, also including the `alsoletter` macro, but it doesn't work. Why not?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings,xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[alsoletter={*},emph={*},emphstyle={\color{red}}]
% \usepackage{mhchem}

\begin{equation*}
  \label{eq:chem}
  \ce{CaCO3(s) <=>[H2O] 
  Ca2+(aq) + CO3^{2-}(aq)}
\end{equation*}
%
Some text
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The best approach depends on what you want. Do you want to highlight "equation" in the same style as the asterisk? Or should the asterisk have its own style?

Comment: I kinda thought just to highlight the asterisk, but I'm open to both solutions :p

Comment: Also, what should to asterisks that occur elsewhere than at the end of an environment's name?

Comment: Good question. My point is to emphasise the asterisks to make an unnumbered equation. My needs right now doesn't have other asterisks, but for a not-so-localised answer it would be nice to be able to have normal asterisks in the rest of the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no really robust way of doing that in `listings`. Declaring `*` as a letter will break highlighting of keywords that are immediately preceded or followed by `*` (e.g. `int*`). Here, I would abuse the `literate` key; see below.

For information, the test in my `\processAsterisk` macro is a hacky way of highlighting asterisks only in `listings`' "normal" mode, not within strings, comments, and other delimited stuff.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\processAsterisk{%
  \ifnum\lst@mode=\lst@Pmode\relax%
    \textcolor{red}{*}%
  \else
    *%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  literate={*}{\processAsterisk}1,
  morecomment=[l]\%,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
% \usepackage{mhchem}

\begin{equation*}
  \label{eq:chem}
  \ce{CaCO3(s) <=>[H2O] 
  Ca2+(aq) + CO3^{2-}(aq)} % 2 * 2 == 4
\end{equation*}
%
Some text
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach could be with `moredelim` key:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings,color}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}
\lstdefinestyle{star}{%
  moredelim=[is][\itshape\color{red}]{|}{|}}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=star]
% \usepackage{mhchem}

\begin{equation|*|}
  \label{eq:chem}
  \ce{CaCO3(s) <=>[H2O] 
  Ca2+(aq) + CO3^{2-}(aq)}
\end{equation|*|}
%
Some text
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

> [image]