# Having asterisk above and not inline in code listings

Tags: spacing, listings, kerning

I want to writing code listings with asterisk in-line not above line.

That is something like this:

[image]

But when I tried this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
*i
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

I ended up getting this:

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: Definitely related (possible duplicate?): [Higher Asterisks in lstlisting environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/303465/134144)

Answer (score 0):

Try to make it in math mode ${}^{*}$ i. If you also need the asterisk to be tight to the letter `i` consider negative spaces.

Comment: `lstlisting` typesets the `$` instead of switching to math mode.