# Listings unexpectedly descends the star(*) character

Tags: fonts, xetex, listings

Using the Fontspec package in XeLaTeX, I declared a new mono font(Menlo) as the font for the listings package. But the package unexpectedly descends the star(*) character, which is weird. How to figure it out? Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{listings}
\newfontfamily\menlo{Menlo}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item \begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\menlo]
select * from instructor
\end{lstlisting}

\item \menlo select * from instructor
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: listings substitutes the * by `\textasteriskcentered` and this seems to be quite low in your font. You can change this see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/303477/2388

Comment: Thanks a lot for your inspiring answer!