# When combining listings and JetBrains Mono * glyphs drop to the baseline (and are too big)

Tags: listings, star

Preparing a book where I use [JetBrains Mono](https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/mono/) ([Github Repo](https://github.com/JetBrains/JetBrainsMono)) (JBM) for code I noticed that in all the listings the * characters where rendered far to deep (on the baseline) and quite big.  Also the *** ligature came out as three (fallen) * glyphs.

At this point JBM was declared as a new family:

```
\newfontfamily\JBMmdfamily{JetBrains Mono}[
  UprightFont    = *-Regular,
  ItalicFont     = *-Italic,
  BoldFont       = *-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic
]
```

After fiddling around a bit I found that adding `{*}{*}1 {***}{{***}}3` entries to a `literate` key in `\lstset{}` seemed to work.  So I exchanged those characters by themselves which is funny but it works.  Sort of.  Looking closer I noticed that in the output spaces *after* those characters disappeared.  Adding the keepspaces setting remedied that, so:

```
\lstset{
  keepspaces        = true,
%   showspaces        = false,
  literate  = {*}{*}1 {***}{{***}}3
}
```

(`showspaces = true`a lets other funny things happen but that is out of scope here.)

Later I noticed that just using

```
\setmonofont{JetBrains Mono}[…]
```

instead of

```
\newfontfamily\JBMmdfamily{JetBrains Mono}[…]
```

with the same body solved *all* those issues, no other \foo needed.  I just don’t understand how that works.  Someone care to explain?

My new problem now is, I *need* `\texttt` (etc.) to switch to the text typewriter type.

Here’s sort of a MWE:

```
    %!TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,listings}

\setmonofont{JetBrains Mono}[
  UprightFont    = *-Regular,
  ItalicFont     = *-Italic,
  BoldFont       = *-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic,
]

\newfontfamily\JBMmdfamily{JetBrains Mono}[
  UprightFont    = *-Regular,
  ItalicFont     = *-Italic,
  BoldFont       = *-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic,
]

\parskip=3mm
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}

\subsection*{Both bindings seem to function:}

ttfamily:    {\ttfamily x*y * z + a *** b }

JBMmdfamily: {\JBMmdfamily x*y * z + a *** b }

\subsection*{listings needs either \textbackslash{}ttfamily:}
lstlisting/ttfamily:       \lstinline[basicstyle = \ttfamily]! x*y * z + a *** b !

lstlisting/JBMmdfamily: \lstinline[basicstyle = \JBMmdfamily]! x*y * z + a *** b !

\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle = \ttfamily]
\ttfamily:     x*y * z + a *** b
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle = \JBMmdfamily]
\JBMmdfamily:  x*y * z + a *** b
\end{lstlisting}

\subsection*{… or keepspace \& literate:}
\lstset{
  keepspaces        = true,
  % showspaces        = true,
  literate  = {*}{*}1 {***}{{***}}3
}

lstlisting/ttfamily:       \lstinline[basicstyle = \ttfamily]! x*y * z + a *** b !

lstlisting/JBMmdfamily: \lstinline[basicstyle = \JBMmdfamily]! x*y * z + a *** b !

\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle = \ttfamily]
\ttfamily:     x*y * z + a *** b
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle = \JBMmdfamily]
\JBMmdfamily:  x*y * z + a *** b
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Any ideas?  Thanks for all nudges and pointers …

Just corrected the source and added a picture of my result.  There were a few errors, sorry for that.

Comment: I don't have your font, but perhaps you can use this https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/303477/2388

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The fonts are available at https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/mono/#intro

Comment: @Thérèse: Thanks for mentioning that.  I included links above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `listings` package uses `\textasteriskcentered` when it finds `*`; if the font has the character at U+2217, it uses it and, lo and behold, the character in the JetBrains Mono font at that slot is a lowered big asterisk. Unless the family is `\ttdefault`.

In the package we find

```
\lst@ProcessOther {"2A}{\lst@ttfamily*\textasteriskcentered}
```

which exactly means what I described above.

It turns out, however, that if the definition is changed to use `\lst@ttfamily**`, the ligature only works in `\lstinline` and not in a full fledged `lstlisting` environment (characters are treated in different ways). Thus `literate` is needed anyway.

Note: font selection is slightly different because I don't have the fonts available in the system, so I need to call them by file name.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,listings}

\setmonofont{JetBrainsMono}[
  Extension      = .ttf,
  UprightFont    = *-Regular,
  ItalicFont     = *-Italic,
  BoldFont       = *-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont = *-Bold-Italic,
]

\newfontfamily\JBMmdfamily{JetBrainsMono}[
  Extension      = .ttf,
  UprightFont    = *-Regular,
  ItalicFont     = *-Italic,
  BoldFont       = *-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont = *-Bold-Italic,
]

\makeatletter
\lst@CCPutMacro\lst@ProcessOther{"2A}{\lst@ttfamily**}\@empty\z@\@empty
\makeatother

\lstset{
  keepspaces = true,
  % showspaces = true,
  % literate = {***}{{***}}3,
}

\begin{document}

The wrong character:{\ttfamily x\textasteriskcentered y}

\bigskip

ttfamily:    {\ttfamily x*y * z + a *** b }

JBMmdfamily: {\JBMmdfamily x*y * z + a *** b }


lstlisting/ttfamily:       \lstinline[basicstyle = \ttfamily]! x*y * z + a *** b !

lstlisting/JBMmdfamily: \lstinline[basicstyle = \JBMmdfamily]! x*y * z + a *** b !

\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle = \ttfamily]
\ttfamily:     x*y * z + a *** b
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle = \JBMmdfamily]
\JBMmdfamily:      x*y * z + a *** b
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Uncommenting the `literate` line yields, instead

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but … I know.  ;-)  You even don’t have to define \threestar, as ```literate  = {*}{*}1 {***}{{***}}3``` works perfectly—I just don’t understand why or how.  It seems that \texttt does a few things that macros produced by \newfontfamily don’t which in turn makes only \texttt work with listings (without using esoteric tricks like those above ;-).

Comment: @Moss_the_TeXie Reworked.