# Follow-Up to "Higher Asterisks in lstlisting environment"

Tags: listings

In the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/303465/higher-asterisks-in-lstlisting-environment), the following solution is suggested to raise an asterisk:

```tex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{stringColor}{RGB}{42,0.0,255}
\definecolor{keyword1Color}{RGB}{63,127,95}
\definecolor{keyword2Color}{RGB}{63,127,200}
\definecolor{singleLineCommentColor}{RGB}{127,0,85}
\definecolor{multiLineCommentColor}{RGB}{200,0,127}

\lstdefinelanguage{test}{
    basicstyle=\linespread{0.83}\small\ttfamily, % Global Code Style
    %literate=*{*}{\normalfont{*}}1,
    morecomment=[l][\color{singleLineCommentColor}]{//},
    morecomment=[s][\color{multiLineCommentColor}]{/*}{*/},
    morestring=[b]",
    morestring=[b]',
    commentstyle=\color{commentColor},
    keywordstyle=[1]{\bfseries\color{keyword1Color}},
    keywordstyle=[2]{\bfseries\color{keyword2Color}},
    stringstyle=\color{stringColor},
    %...
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=test]
    /* Bad asterisk placement! */
x**3
\end{lstlisting}    

\makeatletter
\lst@CCPutMacro
    \lst@ProcessOther {"2A}{%
      \lst@ttfamily 
         {\raisebox{2pt}{*}}% used with ttfamily
         \textasteriskcentered}% used with other fonts
    \@empty\z@\@empty
\makeatother  

\begin{lstlisting}[language=test]
    /* good asterisk placement! */
x**3
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

I noticed two things:

i) The code only works if the line

```tex
basicstyle=\linespread{0.83}\small\ttfamily, % Global Code Style
    %literate=*{*}{\normalfont{*}}1,
```

is used in the `test` environment, which I don't want to use, however, as it seems to change the fonttype. Any way to keep the usual fonttype of `lstlisting`?

ii) How is it possible to have a "usual" and a raised asterisk in the same `lstlisting` environment, which is not possible with the solution?

Thanks.

EDIT: I'm afraid there seems to be a bug in the answer: When I write

```latex
\begin{lstlisting}[language=test]
test_one, test_two = do_tests()
\end{lstlisting}
```

the output contains an asterisk where there shouldn't be one!? How can that be?
[image]

EDIT 2: While we're getting closer, when using `>` or `<`, also the edited solution breaks, I'm afraid:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
    % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/654560/follow-up-to-higher-asterisks-in-lstlisting-environment
    \makeatletter
    \lst@CCPutMacro
    \lst@ProcessOther {"2A}{%
        \lst@ttfamily 
        {\raisebox{2pt}{*}}% used with ttfamily
        {\raisebox{1pt}{*}}% used with other fonts
    }
    \lst@ProcessOther{"40}{\textasteriskcentered}% centered asterisk typed as @
    \@empty\z@\@empty
    \makeatother  
    
    \begin{lstlisting}[language=python, alsoletter={[,]}]
        # Regular font 
        x**3
        # Using "at" symbol to print centered asterisk 
        x@@3
        
        test_one, test_two = do_tests()
        x > y
        x < y
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

leads to this output:
[image]

How can the asterisk be fixed this time, and why does it occur in the first time? I thought we *baked* it?

EDIT 3: There seems to be a nasty interference when I want to use nice `~` and a literate, as proposed in the answer:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
    
    % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17266/how-to-insert-a-nice-tilde-in-a-lstlisting
    \lstset{
        literate={~} {$\sim$}{1}
    }
    
    \makeatletter
    \lst@CCPutMacro
    \lst@ProcessOther {"2A}{%
        \lst@ttfamily 
        {\raisebox{0pt}{*}}% used with ttfamily
        {\raisebox{1pt}{*}}% used with other fonts
    }
    \@empty\z@\@empty
    \makeatother  
    
    \begin{lstlisting}[language=python, literate={(*)}{\textasteriskcentered}{1}]
        /* Raised and cencetred asterisks */
        x**3, x(*)(*)3
        x[~mask] = 0
    \end{lstlisting}
    
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

When I leave out `literate={(*)}{\textasteriskcentered}{1}`, the output looks like this:

[image]

How can I use both the literate and simultaneously have a nice-looking `~`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Update 24-08-2022:

There is a much easier and much more flexible approach to replace something inside `lstlisting`.

In **5.4 Literate programming** section of the [manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/listings) it's described `literate` key that does exactly what you're trying to achieve -- replace something with custom text.

[image]

Thus the solution to your problem as simple as adding

```
literate={(*)}{\textasteriskcentered}{1}
```

to your `test` language definition.

Note that it's really flexible since you're not limited to a single character replacement, but any sequence. The option written above replaces all occurrences of `(*)` with a regular (centered by default) asterisk. So basically if you want, you can change `(*)` to `myCenteredAsterisk` or anything you find convenient and simple to use.

However, using this approach to replace all `*` with raised ones doesn't work well, since multline comments will be broken, so you will have to use the old approach for `*` replacement.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{stringColor}{RGB}{42,0.0,255}
\definecolor{keyword1Color}{RGB}{63,127,95}
\definecolor{keyword2Color}{RGB}{63,127,200}
\definecolor{singleLineCommentColor}{RGB}{127,0,85}
\definecolor{multiLineCommentColor}{RGB}{200,0,127}

\lstdefinelanguage{test}{
    literate={(*)}{\textasteriskcentered}{1},
    morecomment=[l][\color{singleLineCommentColor}]{//},
    morecomment=[s][\color{multiLineCommentColor}]{/*}{*/},
    morestring=[b]",
    morestring=[b]',
%    alsoletter={[,]},
    commentstyle=\color{commentColor},
    keywordstyle=[1]{\bfseries\color{keyword1Color}},
    keywordstyle=[2]{\bfseries\color{keyword2Color}},
    stringstyle=\color{stringColor},
}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\lst@CCPutMacro
    \lst@ProcessOther {"2A}{%
      \lst@ttfamily 
         {\raisebox{2pt}{*}}% used with ttfamily
         {\raisebox{1pt}{*}}% used with other fonts
      }
    \@empty\z@\@empty
\makeatother  

\begin{lstlisting}[language=test]
/* Raised and cencetred asterisks */
    x**3, x(*)(*)3
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

With a predefined language, such as `python`, just use

```latex
\begin{lstlisting}[language=python, literate={(*)}{\textasteriskcentered}{1}]
        /* Raised and cencetred asterisks */
        x**3, x(*)(*)3
\end{lstlisting}
```

[image]

---

Despite the approach above is suggested, the original way to go can be fixed as well. Since `,` is a special character in `lstlisting`, it uses some intermediate macros that contain `@` in it, thus a weird extra asterisk before a comma. To fix it, you can *bake* `,` to be treated as a letter by adding

```
alsoletter={[,]}
```

option to `test` language definition. In case you use a predefined language, such as `python`, just do

```latex
\begin{lstlisting}[language=python, alsoletter={[,]}]
   text... 
\end{lstlisting}
```

## Original Answer:

### Asterisk with any font

[Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer) intentionally put comments to the code so that you can follow how it works.

Specifically, this part

```
\lst@ttfamily 
         {\raisebox{2pt}{*}}% used with ttfamily
         \textasteriskcentered}% used with other fonts
```

from here you immediately can understand why this doesn't work if you remove `basicstyle` option that contains `\ttfamily` which makes the changes apply when **t**ypewri**t**er **family** font is used, otherwise `\textasteriskcentered` put.

Probably it would be easier to follow if the code was formatted this way

```
\lst@ttfamily{<when tt font>}{<any other font>}
```

So that if you want to have the asterisk raised up despite on the font, simply replace

```
\lst@ttfamily{...}{...}
```

with

```
\raisebox{2pt}{*}
```

[image]

IMHO, with the normal font the asterisk is a bit too high, so I would use

```
\lst@ttfamily 
     {\raisebox{2pt}{*}}% used with ttfamily
     {\raisebox{1pt}{*}}% used with other fonts
```

instead.

### Using both raised and centered asterisks

Since `lstlisting` is a verbatim environment, you cannot accomplish the task via user-defined macros to typeset a centered asterisk, so you will have to change another symbol in the same way.

For example, this part of code will replace all `@` with centered asterisks.

```
\lst@ProcessOther{"40}{\textasteriskcentered}
```

If you want to use another symbol instead, pass its ascii code in HEX as a first argument of `\lst@ProcessOther` with leading `"` that lets LaTeX to know it's actually a HEX number. You can use a [converter](https://www.binaryhexconverter.com/ascii-text-to-hex-converter) to easily find out the HEX code of any character.

### Full MWE

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{stringColor}{RGB}{42,0.0,255}
\definecolor{keyword1Color}{RGB}{63,127,95}
\definecolor{keyword2Color}{RGB}{63,127,200}
\definecolor{singleLineCommentColor}{RGB}{127,0,85}
\definecolor{multiLineCommentColor}{RGB}{200,0,127}

\lstdefinelanguage{test}{
    basicstyle=\linespread{0.83}\small, % Global Code Style
    morecomment=[l][\color{singleLineCommentColor}]{//},
    morecomment=[s][\color{multiLineCommentColor}]{/*}{*/},
    morestring=[b]",
    morestring=[b]',
    commentstyle=\color{commentColor},
    keywordstyle=[1]{\bfseries\color{keyword1Color}},
    keywordstyle=[2]{\bfseries\color{keyword2Color}},
    stringstyle=\color{stringColor},
    alsoletter={[,]} % was added after an edit
}
\lstdefinelanguage{testt}{
    basicstyle=\linespread{0.83}\small\ttfamily, % Global Code Style
    morecomment=[l][\color{singleLineCommentColor}]{//},
    morecomment=[s][\color{multiLineCommentColor}]{/*}{*/},
    morestring=[b]",
    morestring=[b]',
    commentstyle=\color{commentColor},
    keywordstyle=[1]{\bfseries\color{keyword1Color}},
    keywordstyle=[2]{\bfseries\color{keyword2Color}},
    stringstyle=\color{stringColor},
    alsoletter={[,]} % was added after an edit
}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\lst@CCPutMacro
    \lst@ProcessOther {"2A}{%
      \lst@ttfamily 
         {\raisebox{2pt}{*}}% used with ttfamily
         {\raisebox{1pt}{*}}% used with other fonts
      }
    \lst@ProcessOther{"40}{\textasteriskcentered}% centered asterisk typed as @
    \@empty\z@\@empty
\makeatother  

\begin{lstlisting}[language=test]
    /* Regular font */
x**3
    /* Using "at" symbol to print centered asterisk */
x@@3
\end{lstlisting}
\medskip
\begin{lstlisting}[language=testt]
    /* Regular font */
x**3
    /* Using "at" symbol to print centered asterisk */
x@@3
\end{lstlisting}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please see my edited question.

Comment: @Hermi updated the answer as well

Comment: I'm afraid there's another problem, please see my edited question.

Comment: @Hermi without full MWE, I can't tell what's the problem in your case. For me, it works perfectly https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3gtV.png

Comment: I edited my question with a full MWE.

Comment: @Hermi Then again you have two options, add `<` and `>` into `alsoletter=` key as we did with a comma, so that you have `alsoletter={<,>,[,]}`. However, it's a fragile way, since `@` is a special character and it's used all over the source [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGZEY.png) and you will have to add to `alsoletter=`  for each character that produces unexpected asterisk. So you'd better give up this approach and use suggested `literate=` approach that's even more flexible.

Comment: Please see my edited question for a problem when trying to use the literate approach.

Comment: @Hermi honestly, it's going further and further from the original question. If you have additional `listings` questions, you can create an additional post, so other can be involved into a help, because it's less likely that people are tracking all the edits in posts.

Comment: @Hermi anyway, the new problem is expected, since adding `literate=` option overrides the global one, so you need to add `~` change manually to have something like `literate={~}{$\sim$}{1} {(*)}{\textasteriskcentered}{1}`